VueJs render function not re-rendering new dynamic component when it changes
Disclaimer: This problem is not exactly related to vue-router but it's easiest for me to demonstrate the issue by reference to vue-router. It's a core problem vue-router solves but I just need a solution to the same problem (maybe in a simpler alternative way). Don't "XY" me.
I'm trying to implement a very simple alternative to the vue-router plugin, for reasons ... Like vue-router I have the two components RouterLink and RouterView and some routing table. Clicking a RouterLink causes the plugin to use the lookup table to find a new component to render which is rendered by the ViewRouter.
The way I've implemented it, ViewRouter has a ref to the component it should render which is updated by the plugin middleware. Problem is, even though render() of the ViewRouter component is called and the component ref has a new value, the content actually rendered to the browser never changes. It's like Vue runtime decided it doesn't need to re-render. What am I doing wrong? How to solve?
Sample code:
import { type App, type Component, defineComponent, h, type PropType, shallowRef, ref } from 'vue';
import HomeView from './HomeView.vue';
import AboutView from './AboutView.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: AboutView,
  }
];

const currentComponent = shallowRef<Component>(() => h('div', h('h1', 'Default')));

export function createRouter() {
    return (app: App) => {
      app.component('router-link', RouterLink);
      app.component('router-view', RouterView);
    };
}

function matchTo(to: string) {
  for(const route of routes) {
    if(route.path === to) {
      return route;
    }
  }
}

function setTo(to: string) {
  const route = matchTo(to);
  console.log('setComponentTo', to, route);
  if(!route) return;
  currentComponent.value = route.component;
}

export const RouterLink = defineComponent({
  name: 'RouterLink',
  props: {
    to: {
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => {
      return h(
        'a',
        {
          onClick: () => setTo(props.to),
        },
        slots.default && slots.default()
      );
    };
  },
});

export const RouterView = defineComponent({
  name: 'RouterView',
  setup() {
    const view = currentComponent.value ? h(currentComponent.value) : [];
    return () => {
      console.log('View render', (currentComponent.value as any).__file);
      return h('div', [view]);
    };
  }
});

Full demo project

"for reasons" - this looks like a good exercise but sounds like XY problem. Consider asking about your problem with vue-router if you're not interested in reinventing a whee.

That's exactly why I said "for reasons". Because I've investigated the problem and concluded I can't do it and anticipated someone would freaken "XY problem" me ...

Since you're aware of "XY", you know of a possibility of going the wrong way instead of delegating the investigation to the crowd. Any way, it's up to you, as long as the immediate problem is answerable, no need for defensive stance, most people are here to help

You lose reactivity in the line with if. I don't really understand its meaning, but if you pass h(currentComponent.value) directly to h, the code starts working. Here is my version of RouterView:
    export const RouterView = defineComponent({
      name: 'RouterView',
      setup() {
        return () => {
          console.log('View render', (currentComponent.value as any).__file);
          return h('div', [h(currentComponent.value)]);
        };
      }
    });

Or the ternary construct must be computed...

By "if" do you mean currentComponent.value ? h(currentComponent.value)? This is true, using the same vnode results in caching and prevents it from being rerendered

Yes, that's the line I was referring to.

Summary: it was a simple mistake of setting the "view" variable in setup() instead of in the render function itself, so either don't set the view variable at all (above solution) or put the variable in the render function.

I think variables in the render function is a bad practice. You can use computed

view is not reactive. It's a variable holding the value of currentComponent.value at the time setup function is run (which happens once, when the component is first evaluated). If you want view's value to update when currentComponent changes, place the expression inside a computed(() => /* expression here */) and return h('div', [h(view.value)])
